# Pausing HTML Embedded Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm using this kind of cross-broswer embedding:

```
<video width="549" height="309" controls poster="video/stills/index_demo_videoScreen.jpg" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <source src="video/2014-reel-web.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video/2014-reel-web.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <embed width="549" height="309" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="video/2014-reel-web.swf">
</video>
```

It's not the "video for everyone" solution, but it is a lot simpler.  Whatever it doesn't work on, I don't particularly care.

What I need to know is how can I stop the video from playing when the user navigates away from it (as it will still be on the page, just not visible)?

I have this:

```
$("video").each(function(index) {
    $(this)[0].pause();
});
```

But that doesn't work if the video has had to fall back to the swf object.  Is it even possible to target it and get it to stop playing?

One thing I tried was using jQuery to replace the HTML content of the video tag with nothing (on the theory that I could rebuild the contents, thus resetting things) but even that just silently does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I got it to work with pure JavaScript ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RL357/33/)) but as you said this solution does not apply to older browsers that don't support `<video>`.

For new browsers add `onblur="vpause()"` to `video` element then this:

```
var test = document.getElementById('video');
test.addEventListener("play", vfocus, false)
test.focus();
function vfocus(){
    test.focus();
}
function vpause() {
    test.pause();
}
```

For old browsers:

http://mediaelementjs.com/

Comment: I know that play() and pause() aren't jQuery functions, the problem is that IE8 doesn't *have* a video object, it falls back to the <embed>.  So the play() and pause() functions are unsupported.

Comment: Good find.  Things are working better, but: I *still* can't get the videos to pause.  Its really frustrating.

Comment: You should post a fiddle. Maybe someone can figure it out.

Comment: A fiddle?  Anyway, for my purposes I was able to make a workaround by individually creating the media objects and saving the object to a variable.  There's only four (max).

Comment: Glad you worked it out. BTW fiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/.  Just like the demo I posted in my answer above. Very useful tool. Peace.

Comment: Oh right.  I keep forgetting that jsfiddle is a Thing.  I'll have to whip something up tomorrow, but MediaElement's own demo's Stop All button doesn't work in IE8.  It's weird.

Comment: <Peruse old questions that don't have marked accepted answers> Huh. I remember this.  I know that whatever I did two years ago ended up working 'cause it works today. Have your 25 rep *two years late* good sir.